# Are The Contents Of The Windows Recycle Bin Compressed?

Tags: windows-server-2003, compression, recycle-bin

When things are in the Windows Recycle Bin (Windows Server 2003), *are the contents compressed*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, unless the files you delete are compressed to start with. When files go into the Recycle Bin, they are moved there, so they generally keep whatever attributes they had.